# Show/hide different div(s) clicking outside the div

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, hyperlink

Is it possible to make 3 different links with 3 different modal boxes? Here is my example:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a class="link" href="#">link1</a>
        <div id="layer">
            <p>text 11</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a class="link" href="#">link2</a>
        <div id="layer">
            <p>text 2</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a class="link" href="#">link3</a>
        <div id="layer">
            <p>text3</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

...with JS:

```
$(function () {    
    $('#layer').hide();
    $('.link').click(function (e) {
      var $message = $('#layer');

      if ($message.css('display') != 'block') {
        $message.show();

        var yourClick = true;
        $(document).bind('click.myEvent', function (e) {
          if (!yourClick && $(e.target).closest('#layer').length == 0) {
            $message.hide();
            $(document).unbind('click.myEvent');
          }
          yourClick = false;
        });
      }

      e.preventDefault();
    });
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/innpe/xbJ6u/1/

but 3 different links show the same text (the first one). I understand the problem, but have no ideas how to realize it in one function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line of your click handler:

```
var $message = $('#layer');
```

...just gets a reference to the first `id="layer"` div, it doesn't try to relate that to the item that was clicked. Try this instead:

```
var $message = $(this).next();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xbJ6u/2/

Of course that relies on the structure having the div to be shown as the next sibling of the clicked link. The following is a bit more flexible in that it'll allow you to change the structure of the html a bit (as long as the links and their related hidden divs belong to the same li):

```
var $message = $(this).closest("li").find("#layer");
```

Note that you shouldn't be using the same id for more than one element.